# Having trouble with JOPtionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm a beginner to Java and I'm having some difficulty with a problem. I am using JOPtionPane to ask the user some questions. However, my difficulties are coming from the fact that I don't know how to handle exceptions properly when the user clicks the X or cancel anywhere in the program. Also, when I looked at the Java API and saw how to implement titles, I tried it but now what should be titles are being placed in the text field instead.

Quitting from other parts of the program also yields exceptions in main thread so I would like to be able to catch those and exit gracefully instead of erroring. Also, in the inputdialogs the title "Investment Advisor" is showing up inside the text field instead. I have looked at the API and it seems I am using proper form but obviously not. Same thing for the icons with the inputdialogs. I don't want them to show but the program doesn't compile and says cannot find symbol if I put them within the inputdialogs. It works for the optiondialog though.

**ABOVE IS FROM BEFORE PROBLEM WAS SOLVED**

Greatly appreciate those who are taking the time to read this.

Here is the code (note investment1 and investment2 are just simple static methods with the proper formulas):

**EDITED BELOW CODE; JUST TRYING TO ADD ERROR CHECKING FOR EMPTY STRINGS**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{  
String initialAmt_Str, targetAmt_Str, interestPct_Str, years_Str, result;
double principle = 0, target = 0, interest = 0;
int again = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, time = 0;

NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

do {  
     Object[] options = {"Compute years to reach target amount",
        "Compute target amount given number of years"};

     int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please choose what you would like to do.",
            "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, null);

     if (choice != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) 
     {

        if (choice == 1) 
        {        
           initialAmt_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the principle:", "Investment Advisor", 
           JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

           if (initialAmt_Str != null) 
              principle = Double.parseDouble(initialAmt_Str);

           else 
              System.exit(0);


           interestPct_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the interest rate as a"
                        + " percentage (without the percent sign):", "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 

           if (interestPct_Str != null) 
              interest = Double.parseDouble(interestPct_Str);

           else 
              System.exit(0); 


           years_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the amount of years:", "Investment Advisor", 
           JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

           if (years_Str != null) 
              time = Integer.parseInt(years_Str);

           else 
              System.exit(0);  

           result = "Your target amount given the number of years is " + 
              fmt.format(investment2(principle, interest, time)) + ".";

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, result, "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

           again = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
        }
     }

     else 
        again = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;


     if (choice == 0) 
     {
        initialAmt_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null,"Enter the principle:","Investment Advisor",
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        if (initialAmt_Str != null) 
           principle = Double.parseDouble(initialAmt_Str);

        else 
           System.exit(0);


        interestPct_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the interest rate as a"
                        + " percentage (without the percent sign):", "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 

        if (interestPct_Str != null) 
           interest = Double.parseDouble(interestPct_Str);

        else 
           System.exit(0); 


        targetAmt_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter your target amount:", "Investment Advisor", 
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


        if (targetAmt_Str != null)
           target = Double.parseDouble(targetAmt_Str);

        else
           System.exit(0);

        result = "You will reach your target amount in " + 
              investment1(principle, target, interest) + 
              (investment1(principle, target, interest) == 1 ? " year." : " years.");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, result, "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        again = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;

     }

     if (again != JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
        again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Find Another?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 

} while (again == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user clicks the "x" close button `JOptionPane` will return `JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION`

You should start by checking for this...

```
if (choice != JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
    // Do the normal stuff
} else {
    // Break out of the do loop
    break;
}
```

You should also beware, that using the `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` the way you have, the `JOptionPane` will return the index of the option selected by the user.

That means that a return value of `0` means that the user selected `"Compute years to reach target"` and a return value of `1` means that the user selected `"Compute target given number of years"`

Using `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION` or `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` may not net the results you are expecting...

**Updated with example**

Your restructure allows for a slightly "sneaky" option, instead of using break, I simple set the `again` variable to `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION` when the user closes the option dialog...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String initialAmt_Str, targetAmt_Str, interestPct_Str, years_Str, result;
        double principle, target, interest;
        int again, time;

        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        do {
            Object[] options = {"Compute years to reach target",
                "Compute target given number of years"};

            int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please choose what you would like to do.",
                    "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, null);

            if (choice != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {

                if (choice == 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Compute target given number of years");
                } else if (choice == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Compute years to reach target");
                }

                again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Find Another?");

            } else {
                again = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
            }
        } while (again == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    }
```

**Updated with additional example to handle cancelled input**

So, if the user clicks the "x" button on the input dialogs, they will return `null`.  At this point, you need to check for the `null` result and make choices about how you want to handle it.  In the example below, I simply set the `again` to equal `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String initialAmt_Str, targetAmt_Str, interestPct_Str, years_Str, result;
    double principle, target, interest;
    int again, time;

    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    do {
        Object[] options = {"Compute years to reach target",
            "Compute target given number of years"};

        int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please choose what you would like to do.",
                "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, null);

        if (choice != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {

            again = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
            if (choice == 1) {
                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the principle:", "Investment Advisor");
                if (input != null) {
                    // Process further...
                    System.out.println("Continue processing...");
                } else {
                    again = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
                }
            } else if (choice == 0) {
                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your target amount:", "Investment Advisor");
                if (input != null) {
                    // Process further...
                    System.out.println("Continue processing...");
                } else {
                    again = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
                }
            }

            if (again != JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Find Another?");
            }

        } else {
            again = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
        }
    } while (again == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
}
```

Comment: Just curious .. do you figure this out without even compiling the code?  How do you get such mad skills!!?!

Comment: @Adel Actually, I did a quick test to check what `JOptionPane` would return and checked the source of `JOptionPane` ;)

Comment: @Adel Mind you, a quick check of the JavaDocs would have shown me the same thing ;)

Comment: Ok I edited the code above to include the first break. However, I am still having the same issues as defined above. I tried adding the same thing but with nulls for the inputDialogs and they all still throw exceptions. Also, what do you want mean about using using no/yes_option? Can you elaborate? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @vb When you pass an array of options to `JOptionPane`, it will return the index of the item that the user selected.  Therefore `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` actually has no meaning.  The fact that it actually defined as `0` is a side effect and one you shouldn't rely on.  That is, rely on the static variable where it makes sense to do so, but don't assume it's underlying value...

Comment: Thank you for the revision. However, with this new implementation it now goes back to the Find Another? screen after clicking X or cancel on the optionDialog. The inputDialogs also still throw exceptions after clicking X as well.

Comment: So I take it you're not checking the return result from the input dialogs for `null` values.  That would seem to make sense.  In my testing, it exited just fine...

Comment: It took a while to get it all working the way I wanted it but thanks to your advice I was able to do it. I just have one last question. I am curious as to how I would implement error checking for empty strings in the showInputDialogs? I have tried if/else for string == "" but that doesn't seem to work. I guess I would like another popup to show if the user hasn't input anything saying to input something or press cancel. Thanks again.

Comment: `String` comparison is done by using `String#equals`.  You could use `string == null || string.trim().isEmpty()` instead...