# Checking if string is empty from showInputDialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

I had a previous question on the same code but for a different reason. I didn't want that question to get too cluttered. Here is the link for reference: [Having trouble with JOPtionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897547/having-trouble-with-joptionpane)

I am looking to check if the user does not enter anything in a showInputDialog and to either show an alternate message and bring them back to the original prompt or to just loop through the the same dialog until they close it normally or proceed by entering a number.

The rest of the code is performing exactly the way I want by exiting the program without throwing an exception. I want all of the inputDialogs to behave the same way as what I am trying to do with the test section, not just the first one.

Currently, it will throw a NPE exception when quitting or empty String error when hitting OK with no input.

Here is the code (with investment1 and investment2 being static methods):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{  
String initialAmt_Str, targetAmt_Str, interestPct_Str, years_Str, result;
double principle = 0, target = 0, interest = 0;
int again = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, time = 0;

NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

do {  
     Object[] options = {"Compute years to reach target amount",
        "Compute target amount given number of years"};

     int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please choose what you would like to do.",
            "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, null);

     if (choice != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) 
     {

        if (choice == 1) 
        {        
           initialAmt_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the principle:", "Investment Advisor", 
           JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

           if (initialAmt_Str != null) 
              principle = Double.parseDouble(initialAmt_Str);
```

**BELOW IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO CHECK FOR EMPTY STRINGS**

```
           else {
              if (initialAmt_Str.isEmpty()){
              while (initialAmt_Str.isEmpty()) {
             initialAmt_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the principle:", "Investment Advisor", 
           JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);}}

              if (initialAmt_Str != null) 
                 principle = Double.parseDouble(initialAmt_Str);

              else
                 System.exit(0);}
```

**END TEST SECTION**

```
interestPct_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the interest rate as a"
                        + " percentage (without the percent sign):", "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 

           if (interestPct_Str != null && !interestPct_Str.isEmpty()) 
              interest = Double.parseDouble(interestPct_Str);

           else 
              System.exit(0); 

           years_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the amount of years:", "Investment Advisor", 
           JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

           if (years_Str != null && !years_Str.isEmpty()) 
              time = Integer.parseInt(years_Str);

           else 
              System.exit(0);  

           result = "Your target amount given the number of years is " + 
              fmt.format(investment2(principle, interest, time)) + ".";

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, result, "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

           again = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
        }
     }

     else 
        again = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;


     if (choice == 0) 
     {
        initialAmt_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null,"Enter the principle:","Investment Advisor",
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        if (initialAmt_Str != null && !initialAmt_Str.isEmpty()) 
           principle = Double.parseDouble(initialAmt_Str);

        else 
           System.exit(0);


        interestPct_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the interest rate as a"
                        + " percentage (without the percent sign):", "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 

        if (interestPct_Str != null && !interestPct_Str.isEmpty()) 
           interest = Double.parseDouble(interestPct_Str);

        else 
           System.exit(0); 


        targetAmt_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter your target amount:", "Investment Advisor", 
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


        if (targetAmt_Str != null && !targetAmt_Str.isEmpty())
           target = Double.parseDouble(targetAmt_Str);

        else
           System.exit(0);

        result = "You will reach your target amount in " + 
              investment1(principle, target, interest) + 
              (investment1(principle, target, interest) == 1 ? " year." : " years.");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, result, "Investment Advisor", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        again = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;

     }

     if (again != JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
        again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Find Another?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 

} while (again == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
}
}
```

Comment: And what's the exact problem with the code?

Comment: That is a lot of code for a question title of checking empty string...

Comment: Added error I am receiving.

Comment: Just look at where your `while` loop ends and think about where it *should* end given what you want to achieve. Or just look at the stack trace of your `NullPointerException`; it tells you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: I can get rid of the problem with it throwing an exception when pressing cancel by moving the bottom if/else on top of the if that checks for empty strings. But when pressing ok with no input the program closes and it still throws the empty string exception pointing to the if (.isEmpty()) line

Answer (score 4):

Just add a call to result.isEmpty()

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input Text Here");

if( result.isEmpty() )
{
// quit the loop
}
```

Comment: You love me, You really love me!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if statement **if (initialAmt_Str.isEmpty())** and use only the while loop. The while loop will always be true when the user enters an empty string or when **initialAmt_Str** is empty but when the user enters a valid input, the while loop becomes false thereby breaking the loop

```
else {
   while (initialAmt_Str.isEmpty()) {
             initialAmt_Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the principle:", "Investment Advisor", 
           JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);}

              if (initialAmt_Str != null) 
                 principle = Double.parseDouble(initialAmt_Str);

              else
                 System.exit(0);}
```

here it is